# MutationObserver doesnt detect changes inside querySelectorAll()[]

Tags: javascript, dom, mutation-observers

I hav this code.

```
New MutationObserver(() => {
  const code = document.querySelectorAll('code');
  const parser = JSON.parse(code[10].textContent as string);
  const getData = parser.elements;

  console.log(getData);

 }).observe(document, {
  attributes: true,
  characterData: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  attributeOldValue: true,
  characterDataOldValue: true,
});
```

Currently, MutationObserver doesn't detect the new `querySelectorAll('code')[10].textContent` content in next page.

What do I need to do to detect that changes?

Answer (score 1):

The callback passed into the MutationObserver constructor is what's called when a mutation is observed NOT what's being observed.

You need to call the observe function on your observer with the config of what to observe

```
// Node to observe
const targetNode = document.getElementById('#id');
//Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)

const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    .....
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

**Check out the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)**

Comment: Oh, wait. I forgot to add the .observe(document, {}) at the end of my code. I have that but it still doesnt detect the new parse

Comment: i updated my code above, thats my complete code. @Moshe Sommers

Comment: What do you mean doesn't detect the new parse? Your observer is running? Is the callback being called?